# how to "properly" overlay a div on a scrollable windows "view port"

Tags: css

I need to overlay a div on the top right of a scrollable window's "view port" - or in such a way that when you scroll the behind window, the overlay stays put

https://jsfiddle.net/zgjk1xvh/

^ this works (notice how the overlay doesn't move when you scroll), but I don't think it's the right way to do it. The `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` don't seem normal

here it is too:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="window">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <p>[[ my overlay ]]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}

#window {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: grey;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works. The `width: 100%` isn't required, as your `#window` element is block-level (so will have 100% width already). Regarding the height, you will need it as a non-specified `height` will be based on `#window` element's content. By specifying `height: 100%`, your `#window` element's height will be based on the containing block, which allows `overflow` to work.

So, from what I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your approach.

The other answer mentions `position: fixed`, but based on your question/requirements, I think `position: absolute` is the correct approach. `position: absolute` will be relative to an ancestor with a non-default position value (i.e., `position: static`), and so your `#overlay` will be relative to `#parent`)

Answer (score 0):

Since `position: absolute;` will be relative to the next ancestor element that has `position: relative;`, it's safer to use `position: fixed;` in order to fix the position in relation to the viewport.

(In your case absolute only works as intended since there is no relative ancestor, so `absolute` relates to the `html` element)